# How can i select row from table according to column values of row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i want to select row on condition based on column values in sql server please check below example with required result.

```
 WITH allData
AS (
select mlid=1,value=0,checkid=1
union all
select mlid=2,value=6,checkid=2
union all
select mlid=3,value=6,checkid=1
union all
select mlid=4,value=0,checkid=2
)
select * from allData
```

Result

```
   Mlid  Value checked
    1    0      1
    2    6      2
    3    6      1
    4    0      2
```

required result -->
condition:- if  checked column  values  is 1 and values column is 0 than display checked values values 2 rows only
either display checked column values 1 
like below result

```
Mlid value checked   
2     6      2
3     6      1
```

Comment: so basically don't display the row if "checked" = 1 and "value" = 0? Is that right? Your description of the rules is not very clear. Also you've shown us two different results, but not the raw data from which it came, so it's hard to be certain what the correct query is.

Comment: yes if "checked"=1 and "value"=0 then row will be "checked"=2 and "checked"=1 should have not display but if "checked"=1 and values >0 then display only "checked"=1 row and "checked"=2 should have not display.   i want to apply condition on row by row .

Comment: you're trying to apply a rule for one row based on data from another row. SQL doesn't work like that. Rules in a WHERE clause apply to each row individually, the other rows are considered separately. The rows where checked = 1 have no direct relationship to the rows where checked = 2.

Comment: you can't say "if a row has checked=1 and values > 0 then don't display some other row".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for your sample data, but would fail for pretty much anything else?

```
WITH allData AS (
    SELECT MLID = 1, [VALUE] = 0, CHECKID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MLID = 2, [VALUE] = 6, CHECKID = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MLID = 3, [VALUE] = 6, CHECKID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MLID = 4, [VALUE] = 0, CHECKID = 2)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN a1.CHECKID = 1 AND a1.VALUE = 0 THEN a2.MLID ELSE a1.MLID END AS MLID,
    CASE WHEN a1.CHECKID = 1 AND a1.VALUE = 0 THEN a2.[VALUE] ELSE a1.[VALUE] END AS [VALUE],
    CASE WHEN a1.CHECKID = 1 AND a1.VALUE = 0 THEN a2.CHECKID ELSE a1.CHECKID END AS CHECKID
FROM 
    allData a1
    INNER JOIN allData a2 ON a2.MLID = a1.MLID + 1 AND a2.CHECKID = 2
WHERE
    a1.CHECKID = 1;
```

I guess this might get you started on a better query, or even raise some questions about what you actually need, and how these rows are related?